# Preventing Qmenu's auto disappearing by show() slot

Tags: qt, system-tray, qmenu, qaction

I'm developing  a gui application  with Qt 4.6.3 on Windows platform.In the app,
Qmenu has a submenu and after ı clicked this submenu's QAction the main menu is disappearing.For preventing this, ı used something like this.

```
connect(submenu,SIGNAL(triggered()),mainMenu,SLOT(show()));
```

But this time, main menu doesn't disappear if ı click desktop or anywhere outside the menu.

How can ı solve this problem?

Comment: You have to explicitly call `hide()`. `QMenu` is typically opened by calling [`QMenu::exec()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmenu.html#exec). Note that menus automatically close when an action in the menu or a submenu is clicked, so you're actually just re-opening the menu. There is no property or setting to prevent this, as Qt is simply following platform styles.

Comment: You may try to install an event filter on `QMenu` and it's children `QMenu`'s to prevent hiding. Better way how to do it - research current `QMenu` source code.

Comment: still same issue...